# Fatal error: Class 'Magestore_Featuredproduct_Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php on line 547

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

How can i fix this issue in Magento admin:

Fatal error: Class 'Magestore_Featuredproduct_Helper_Data' not found in app\Mage.php on line 547

Comment: Check if Data.php file exists in the Magestore/Featuresproduct/Helper folder.

Answer (score 2):

Disable compilation if enabled. clear cache

Answer (score 0):

create a file in `<codepool>/Magestore/Featuredproducts/Helper/` with name `Data.php` and paste the following code in it.

```
class Magestore_Featuredproduct_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Data { }
```